# "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages" when installing laravel 5 simple-blog

Tags: php, laravel

When I type "composer create-project laravel/laravel simple-blog" to load simple-blog from the server, I receive an error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- laravel/framework v5.2.6 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.5 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.4 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- Installation request for laravel/framework 5.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.2.0, v5.2.1, v5.2.2, v5.2.3, v5.2.4, v5.2.5, v5.2.6].
```

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: Find the `;extension=php_mbstring.dll` in your `php.ini` file and remove the semi-colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error tells you everything you need to know.

You are simply missing a required PHP extension, `Mbstring`.

You either need to install the package or enable it through your `php.ini` file.

**php.ini**

Find this line `;extension=php_mbstring.dll` and uncomment it by removing the `;` so it reads `extension=php_mbstring.dll`

Or just run `php5enmod mbstring` if your system allows it

**Install it**

In a linux/debian based system it would just be `apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5`. The package includes the extension as well as everything else you need for Laravel. Considering you have no other errors on install, you likely already have this and just need to enable it in your `php.ini` file

Comment: @BG.Naruto please mark this as the accepted answer then, and if you found it helpful then consider upvoting it.